# Django form should remain same after submit button clicked

Tags: python, django, django-forms

i am making stopwords removal api with using django.when i submit user text input fairly getting output but text area not visible after getting output.my requirement is below output is displaying input should remain same.

[image]
[image]

below code
as u can see in image snapshots is the text area is invisible.so it shoul be visible

views.py

```
   from django.shortcuts import render,redirect,HttpResponse
   from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
   from .forms import ReportForm
   from django.views import View
   import spacy
   import pdb
   nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
class stopwordsremoval(FormView):
template_name = 'report.html'
form_class = ReportForm


def form_valid(self, form):
    document1 = ((form.cleaned_data.get('text')))

    return redirect('report_details', document1)


            class ReportDetails(View):
                   def get(self,request,document1):
                                 word_lemma = []

    #pdb.set_trace()
    for word in (nlp(document1)):
        a = (word.is_stop, word.text)
        word_lemma.append(a)
    searchedData = (word_lemma)
    return render(request, 'report.html', {'naturallanguageprocessing': searchedData})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
class ReportForm(forms.Form):

text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 5, 'cols': 100}))
```

report.html

```
  {% extends 'base.html' %}

  {% block content %}
  <h1>StopWordsRemoval</h1>
      <div>
      <form action = "" method = "post" >
           {% csrf_token %}

              {{ form.as_p}}


      <button type="submit">stopwordsremoval</button>
           </div>



      <div >
         <ul>

    <li>{{ naturallanguageprocessing }}</li>

   [![enter image description here][1]][1]</ul>
   <a href="{% url 'stopwordsremoval' %}" </a>
        <style>
           div {
                  width: 1000px;
                  border: 5px solid green;
                  padding: 10px;
                  margin: 10px;
                 }
                 </style>
                   </div>
               </div>

            {% endblock %}


      [![this is the user input we are giving][1]][1]






        [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlSlL.png

    [![this output the text area is not visible have to make visible][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M80Un.png
```

Comment: Then you should make an AJAX call.

Comment: Thanks,but can you tell me please tell me what mistakes I made in above code.I am new to using ajax ,can you please explain how can i use ajax to overcome this issue